# I'm trying to write an if condition to give a response if there is a change in balance

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

```
pragma solidity >0.7.0 <=0.9.0;

contract demoCoin {
    address public Owner;
    mapping(address => uint256) myCoin;

    constructor() {
        Owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function loadCoin(uint256 amount) public {
        require(Owner == msg.sender);
        myCoin[Owner] += amount;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint256 amount)
        public
        returns (string memory, uint256)
    {
        require(Owner == msg.sender);
        if (amount > myCoin[msg.sender]) revert("Insufficient balance");
        myCoin[msg.sender] -= amount;
        myCoin[receiver] += amount;

        // I want to return the alert for a successful transaction
        if (myCoin[receiver] += amount) {
            return string = "You have been credited with" + amount + "demoCoin";
        }
    }

    function showBal() public view returns (uint256) {
        return myCoin[msg.sender];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `event` to register a specific action in smart contract. You must to declare an event with this statement:

```
event [NameEvent] ([typeof] [nameVariable], [typeof] [nameVariable2]);
```

and to register an event you can use this statement:

```
emit [NameEvent] ([valueVariable], [valueVariable2]);
```

In your case, you declare an event in this way:

```
...
constructor (){
    Owner = msg.sender;
}

// Declare event
event SuccessfullTransfer(address receiver, uint amount);

function loadCoin(uint amount) public {
    require(Owner == msg.sender);
    myCoin[Owner] += amount;
}
....
```

and you must to call it in `sendCoin()` function (in this case) in this way:

```
function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) public {
     require(Owner == msg.sender);
     if (amount > myCoin[msg.sender])
     revert ('Insufficient balance');
     myCoin[msg.sender] -= amount;
     myCoin[receiver] += amount;


     // I want to return the alert for a successful transaction 

    if (myCoin[receiver] += amount)
    { 
       emit SuccessfullTransfer(receiver, amount);
    }
```

When a single user's interacting with `sendCoin()` function and transfer their coin to smart contract, you can see the event in the transaction.

Note: If you'll use  this way, you have to change the return type of `sendCoin()` function.

More information on the events [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_events.htm).